# Spawning care-o-bot gripper in gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, care-o-bot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, and thanks in advance!

there is a way to spawn just the gripper of Care-o-Bot/PR2 in Gazebo? I tried:

```
export ROBOT=cob3-2
roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch
rosrun gazebo spawn_model -file `pwd`/sdh.urdf.xacro -urdf -z 1 -model my_hand
```

but it didn't work and being honest I'm not sure about what I'm doing. Could someone indicates me some document/tutorial? I did the [cob_bringup](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cob_bringup) tutorial but it explain you how to simulate all the robot together.
Thanks again.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10495/spawning-care-o-bot-gripper-in-gazebo/) by [Bemfica](https://answers.ros.org/users/540/bemfica/) on ROS Answers with karma: 482 on 2011-07-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can wrap the xacro in your own model file, anchoring the gripper to a dummy link:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:sensor="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#sensor"
       xmlns:controller="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#controller"
       xmlns:interface="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#interface"
       xmlns:xacro="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#interface"
       name="sdh" >
  
  <!-- The following included files set up definitions of parts of the robot body -->
  <!-- cob sdh-->
  <include filename="$(find cob_description)/ros/urdf/sdh_v0/sdh.urdf.xacro" />

  <!-- foot for arm-->
  <link name="dummy_link">
          <inertial>
             <origin xyz="0 0 -10" rpy="0 0 0"/>
             <mass value="1000.0"/>
             <inertia ixx="100.0"  ixy="0"  ixz="0" iyy="100.0" iyz="0" izz="100.0" />
          </inertial>

          <visual>
             <origin xyz="0 0 0.25" rpy="0 0 0" />
             <geometry>
                    <box size="0.6 0.4 0.4"/>
                    <!--cylinder radius="0.1" length="0.5"/-->
             </geometry>
             <material name="Blue" />
          </visual>

          <collision>
             <origin xyz="0 0 0.25" rpy="0 0 0" />
             <geometry>
                    <box size="0.6 0.4 0.4"/>
                    <!--cylinder radius="0.1" length="0.5"/-->
             </geometry>
          </collision>
  </link>
  
  <!-- sdh -->
  <xacro:cob_sdh_v0 name="sdh" parent="dummy_link">
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 3.1415926 0" />
  </xacro:cob_sdh_v0>

</robot>
```

save it as `test.urdf.xacro` in your own ros package (`my_own_foo_ros_pkg`).
Then construct a launch script to push the xacro file onto the parameter server:

```
<launch>
  <!-- send pr2 urdf to param server -->
  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find my_own_foo_ros_pkg)/test.urdf.xacro'" />
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`sdh.urdf.xacro` is a [xacro](http://ros.org/wiki/xacro) file, you need to convert it into [urdf](http://ros.org/wiki/urdf) first.  You'll need some code somewhere that makes use of the `cob_sdh_v0` macro described in the xacro file.  For example, when the gripper is attached to the arm [arm_sdh.urdf.xacro](https://github.com/ipa320/cob_common/blob/master/cob_description/ros/robots/arm_sdh.urdf.xacro), it is invoked by following code blocks:

```
<!-- cob sdh-->
<include filename="$(find cob_description)/ros/urdf/sdh_v0/sdh.urdf.xacro" />
<!-- sdh -->
<xacro:cob_sdh_v0 name="sdh" parent="arm_7_link">
  <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 3.1415926 0" />
</xacro:cob_sdh_v0>
```

I suggest taking a look at the tutorials in xacro and urdf packages first.

John

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-07-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bemfica](https://answers.ros.org/users/540/bemfica/) on 2011-07-06**:
okay. Thank you man! I'll read the xacro tutorials again and I'll try this conversion. I was trying to edit the "main" launch file (sim.launch/cob3-2.launch) to cut off the parts that I'm not interested to (torso/head/arm etc), is it the right way?